# Converting a line of C regexp code to Perl

Tags: c, perl

I'm trying to convert a line of old code from C (which I do not know) to Perl (which I sorta know).

It has a data structure I don't understand, that being a number followed by /* character */

```
if (lSeries != 18 /*S*/ &&  lSeries !=  2 /*C*/ && lSeries != 4  /*E*/ &&  lSeries != 6  /*G*/) {}
```

Comment: A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4, F=5, G=6, ...

Comment: `/* ... */` is a comment. So `if` is true if  `lSeries` variable isn't equal to any of those numbers

Answer (score 5):

In C, the `/* ... */` construction indicates a comment. It will not be compiled or executed by the program.

So the executable part of that code snippet is

```
if (lSeries != 18 && lSeries != 2 && lSeries != 4 
    && lSeries != 6) {}
```

A literal translation to Perl would be

```
if ($lSeries != 18 && $lSeries != 2 && $lSeries != 4
    && $lSeries != 6) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

/* C style for multiline comments */

C code:

```
if(  lSeries != 18 /*S*/
  && lSeries != 2  /*C*/
  && lSeries != 4  /*E*/
  && lSeries != 6  /*G*/  
) {}
```

#perl style for single line comments. for more please refer [Acme::Comment](https://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/13/comment.html/)

Perl Code:

```
if(  $lSeries != 18 #S
  && $lSeries != 2  #C
  && $lSeries != 4  #E
  && $lSeries != 6  #G 
) {}
```